# Unable to get Android Emulator to start / how to get permissions set right to Kvm

Tags: permissions, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, android-emulator

I can no longer get my Android emulator to launch.
Virtualization is enabled through the BIOS.
When I launch through the command line, I get the following:

```
nin@nin-Gazelle:~$ cd Android/Sdk/tools/
nin@nin-Gazelle:~/Android/Sdk/tools$ kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
nin@nin-Gazelle:~/Android/Sdk/tools$ emulator -avd nexus5
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure KVM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: This user doesn't have permissions to use KVM (/dev/kvm)
```

When I launch through Android Studio, it tells me I have a `permissions issue at /dev/kvm. The current user does not have access.`
How do I set the permissions correctly on /dev/kvm to get my emulator working?
This used to work just fine till I upgraded to 18.04LTS. At least that's when I think the issue started.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt install qemu-kvm
sudo adduser <user> kvm
emulator -avd nexus5 -use-system-libs
```

Comment: Did not help in my case. Still "This user doesn't have permissions to use KVM (/dev/kvm)"